# Core Data KVO count

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, key-value-observing

Is possible to observe the count of some Item, say Users, in Core Data?

I could do something like this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDataModelChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:myManagedObjectContext];

NSSet *insertedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
localCount += [insertedObjects count];

NSSet *deletedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
localCount -= [insertedObjects count];
```

But this seems error prone and their has to be a more direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. It's even easier with NSFetchedResultsController.
In normal case (I mean without NSFetchedResultsController) you do following

```
NSManagedObject *foo; //Some NSManagedObject
[foo addObserver: self forKeyPath:@"A" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld |     NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:context];
```

With NSFetchedResultsController set it's delegate, and then you will receive `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` calls.

---

EDIT:
in your case your approach is correct. The errors must come from somewhere else